# How to customise headers and footers without using a package

Tags: header-footer

I know some of the main commands that control headers and footers in the LaTeX document class [`book`](https://ctan.org/pkg/book) which can be found under the section 6.4 of the Standard Document Classes for the LaTeX documentation, such as

```
\def\ps@headings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
    \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}%
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
        \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
            \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                \if@mainmatter
                    \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
                \fi
            \fi
            ##1}}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
        \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
            \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
                \thesection. \ %
            \fi
        ##1}}}}
```

But how to generate decorations such as a headrule (or footrule) as `fancyhdr` does (I tried inserting `\hrulefill` but it did not work)? How to put the name of the subsection e.g. on left pages headers? I'm just interested on how to do the basic things without calling other packages, also because I want to have a certain control on the output.

I know it's not so specific, but maybe with some examples I can elaborate some ideas on how to edit headings without external packages.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel It is much easier to customise headers and footers with one of the companion packages of titlesec: `titleps`, which can be used independently  from titlesec. No juggling with leftmarks, rightmarks and the like.

Comment: I can understand it, but since I started modifying on my own pre-defined commands trying not to use packages I got much better results, so I would like to do this acting directly on the definitions.

Comment: Yet, you're using LaTeX, a very large  TeX macros package, not plain TeX…

Comment: Yes, I guess it's a gradual process that will end up in the total control when I'll be expert enough, but I'm starting from a point as in everything ;-)

Comment: Also, there are some thing that I don't really mind to control since I find already ok, but other packages which I don't really like, since I can't have what I want

Comment: Just ask how to. Most needs are already taken care of by some package — sometimes it requires some small patch to get *exactly* what you want.

Comment: The `memoir` class has inbuilt commands for customising headers and footers. See *Pagination and headers* in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`).

Comment: Since you question is basically how to do what `fancyhdr`, `memoir` or whatever does without loading them, why don't you look at how they do it? Fine if you want to reinvent the wheel, but there doesn't seem any point in asking other people to reinvent it for you. Just take the wheel you've got apart, twiddle it a bit and put it back together in its new octagonal form. (But don't complain if it doesn't work as well as the circular one you dismantled.)

Comment: @Bernard I'll take the juggling of marks any day :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I globally agree with Bernards comment. 
And why not use the `fancyhdr` or `titleps`packages ?

> generate decorations such as a headrule (or footrule) as fancyhdr does

IMO, headrule or footrule are evil

> How to put the name of the subsection e.g. on left pages headers?

Have you had a try to `\pagestyle{myheadings}` ?

Here are some ideas, assuming that you have used neither `titlesec` nor any other pagestyle packages, and use the standard class `book` with customized `\pagestyle{headings}`.
It uses mostly the patching commads of `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document} 
\makeatletter
  % define headrule and footrule
  \long\def\myline{\linebreak\hb@xt@\textwidth{\hrulefill\par}}
  % collect names from sectioning commands
  \apptocmd{\@chapter}{\gdef\currentchaptername{#1}}{}{}
  \apptocmd{\@schapter}{\gdef\currentchaptername{#1}}{}{}
  \apptocmd{\@sect}{{\ifnum#2=1\gdef\currentsectionname{#7}\else
  \ifnum#2=2 \gdef\currentsubsectionname{#7}\fi\fi}}{}{} 
  % enable multiline header
  \patchcmd{\@outputpage}{\hb@xt@\textwidth{\@thehead}}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\@thehead}}{}{}
  % redefine the \ps@headings macro by inserting \myline and \currentsubsectionname
  \def\ps@headings{%
    \let\@oddfoot\myline \let\@evenfoot\myline
    \ifundef{\currentsectionname}{\def\currentsectionname{}}{}
    \ifundef{\currentsubsectionname}{\def\currentsubsectionname{}}{}
    \long\def\@evenhead{\thepage\quad \slshape\leftmark\hfill \currentsectionname\hfill \currentsubsectionname\myline}%
    \long\def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage\myline}%
    \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
       \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
         \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \if@mainmatter \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ % \fi \fi
          ##1}}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
       \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
         \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@ \thesection. \ \fi
          ##1}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
```

This patching does't alter the toc, and also works with `babel`, and with `hyperref` provided it is loaded after.

Comment: I see there's no simple answer and customisation of headers without `fancyhdr`. I naively thought that there would have been a simple solution, but seems that lot of workaround is needed instead. Thanks anyway for your nice solution!